# Create a member-specific promo code

Tags: expresso-store, discounts

I am relatively sure this can't be done yet, but worth checking. Is it possible to create an Expresso Store promo code that is only available to a specific member/user?

The idea here is to generate a discount promo code as a sort of credit/reward to a user for something he/she did, like register on the site.

The only thing I can think of at the moment is to create an additional table that will link a member to a discount promo entry. And then validate this myself during the checkout process.

Anyone with a better idea without hacking Expresso Store self?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are able to "[**Restrict to Member Groups**](https://exp-resso.com/docs/control_panel_discounts.html)" but not per member.

> If selected, this discount will only be available to logged in members
>   of these member groups.

I'd suggest creating discounts with "Total Use Limit" set to 1 and an extremely unique "Promo Code" that can't be guessed. Use the "Notes" field to store the member ID... You can key off that member ID to do what you like.

Comment: Thanks Anna, I will leave this question a bit to see if there's maybe someone who has done something similar as well before I mark the correct answer, but I appreciate your suggestion. Might need to log a feature request with the Expresso (DevDemon) guys.